# Error "TypeError: this.options.files?.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

so I have a Discord Bot and I wanted to create a memberInfo slashcommand. So I made this code for it:

```
const { ChatInputCommandInteraction, SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, AttachmentBuilder } = require("discord.js");

const { profileImage } = require("discord-arts");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("memberinfo")
    .setDescription("View your or any member's information.")
    .setDMPermission(false)
    .addUserOption((option) => option
        .setName("member")
        .setDescription("View a member's information. Leave empty to view your own")
    ),
    /**
     * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction
     */
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply()
        const member = interaction.options.getMember("member") || interaction.member;

        if(member.user.bot) return await interaction.editReply({
            embeds:
            [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription("At the moment, bots are not supported for this command.")
            ],
            ephemeral: true
        });

        try {
            const fetchedMembers = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();

            const profileBuffer = await profileImage(member.id);
            const imageAttachment = new AttachmentBuilder(profileBuffer, 
            {name: 'profile.png'});

            const joinPosition = Array.from(fetchedMembers
            .sort((a, b) => a.joinedTimestamp - b.joinedTimestamp)
            .keys())
            .indexOf(member.id) + 1;

            const topRoles = member.roles.cache
            .sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position)
            .map(role => role);

            const userBadges = member.user.flags.toArray()

            const joinTime = parseInt(member.joinedTimestamp / 1000);
            const createdTime = parseInt(member.createdTimestamp / 1000);

            const Booster = member.premiumSince ? "<:discordboost7:1086751631221211247>" : "❌";

            const Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor({name: `${member.user.tag} | General Information`, iconURL: member.displayAvatarURL()})
            .setColor(member.displayColor)
            .setDescription(`On <t:${joinTime}:D>, ${member.user.username} joined as the **${addSuffix(joinPosition)}** member of this guild.`)
            .setImage("attachment://profile.png")
            .addFields([
                {name: "Badges", value: `${addBadges(userBadges).join("")}`, inline: true},
                {name: "Booster", value: `${Booster}`, inline: true},
                {name: "Top Roles", value: `${topRoles.join("")}`, inline: false},
                {name: "Created", value: `<t:${createdTime}:R>`, inline: true},
                {name: "Joined", value: `<t:${joinTime}:R>`, inline: true},
                {name: "Identifier", value: `${member.id}`, inline: false},
                {name: "Avatar", value: `[Link](${member.displayAvatarURL()})`, inline: true},
                {name: "Banner", value: `[Link](${(await member.user.fetch()).bannerURL})`, inline: true},
            ]);

            await interaction.editReply({embeds: [Embed], files: {imageAttachment}});
        } catch (error) {
            await interaction.editReply({content: "An error occured: Contact the Developer (MrAplex#9627)"});
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

function addSuffix(number) {
    if(number % 100 >= 11 && number % 100 <= 13)
        return number + "th";

    switch(number % 10) {
        case 1: return number + "st";
        case 2: return number + "nd";
        case 3: return number + "rd";
    }
    return number + "th";
}

function addBadges(badgeNames) {
    if(!badgeNames.length) return ["X"];
    const badgeMap = {
        "ActiveDeveloper": "<:activedeveloper:1086751628423606383>",
        "BugHunterLevel1": "<:discordbughunter1:1086751635860115476>",
        "BugHunterLevel2": "<:discordbughunter2:1086751637416181821>",
        "PremiumEarlySupporter": "<:discordearlysupporter:1086751640410923028>",
        "Partner": "<:discordpartner:1086751645712535723>",
        "Staff": "<:discordmod:1086751641887314013>",
        "HypeSquadOnlineHouse1": "<:hypesquadbravery:1086751651479687199>", // bravery
        "HypeSquadOnlineHouse2": "<:hypesquadbrilliance:1086751653585244202>", // brilliance
        "HypeSquadOnlineHouse3": "<:hypesquadbalance:1086751649810370652>", // balance
        "Hypesquad": "<:hypesquadevents:1086751902542331975>",
        "CertifiedModerator": "<:discordmod:1086751641887314013>",
        "VerifiedDeveloper": "<:discordbotdev:1086751632903131306>",
    };
  
    return badgeNames.map(badgeName => badgeMap[badgeName] || '❔');
}
```

My problem here is that when I type use the slashcommand in Discord, I get an error in Terminal saying the following:

```
/Users/Aplex/Documents/Royal Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessagePayload.js:187
    const attachments = this.options.files?.map((file, index) => ({
                                            ^

TypeError: this.options.files?.map is not a function
    at MessagePayload.resolveBody (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Royal Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessagePayload.js:187:45)
    at InteractionWebhook.editMessage (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Royal Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Webhook.js:336:50)
    at ChatInputCommandInteraction.editReply (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Royal Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:158:36)
    at Object.execute (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Royal Bot/Commands/Public/memberInfo.js:69:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

How do I fix this? I have no Idea what to do. I am guessing the problem is when I typed in code this (inside the try-catch):

```
await interaction.editReply({embeds: [Embed], files:{imageAttachment}});
```

Comment: `this.options.files` is not an array

Comment: soooo what do I have to do then?

Comment: @Konrad It looks like that's library code, not OP's code, so `this` should refer to `MessagePayload`.

Comment: @MrAplex Which line is line 69 of memberInfo.js? It looks like the error is originating there.

Comment: @MichaelM. it's the last code I sent the one with the "imageAttachment"

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix, it was my dumbness :D

If you look at the last code I sent, the `imageAttachment` is inside `{}` instead of `[]`. Changing that fixed the issue.